# Django-book tutorial models Chapter 5

Tags: python, django, django-models, model

I am currently learning Django though the Django-book tutorial and I've come across an error. 
On chapter 5 I am supposed to input this in the python interpreter

```
    >>> p1 = Publisher.objects.create(name='Apress', 
    ... address='2855 Telegraph Avenue', 
    ... city='Berkeley', state_province='CA', country='U.S.A.', 
    ... website='http://www.apress.com/') 
    >>> p2 = Publisher.objects.create(name="O'Reilly", 
    ... address='10 Fawcett St.', city='Cambridge', 
    ... state_province='MA', country='U.S.A.', 
    ... website='http://www.oreilly.com/') 
    >>> publisher_list = Publisher.objects.all() 
    >>> publisher_list
```

According to the tutorial, I should get an output of

```
    [<Publisher: Publisher object>, <Publisher: Publisher object>]
```

However I get the same output but with 4 objects!!

```
    [<Publisher: Publisher object>, <Publisher: Publisher object>, <Publisher: Publisher object>, <Publisher: Publisher object>]
```

Also I am supposed to change my models.py to this (added unicode functions) from django.db import models

```
    class Publisher(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30) 
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50) 
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60) 
    state_province = models.CharField(max_length=30) 
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50) 
    website = models.URLField() 

    def __unicode__(self): 
            return self.name 

    class Author(models.Model): 
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30) 
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40) 
    email = models.EmailField() 

    def __unicode__(self): 
            return u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name) 

    class Book(models.Model): 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100) 
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author) 
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher) 
    publication_date = models.DateField() 

    def __unicode__(self): 
            return self.title
```

In order to display the objects. Here is the output according to the tutorial

```
    >>> from books.models import Publisher 
    >>> publisher_list = Publisher.objects.all() 
    >>> publisher_list 
    [<Publisher: Apress>, <Publisher: O'Reilly>]
```

But I'm still getting

```
    [<Publisher: Publisher object>, <Publisher: Publisher object>, <Publisher: Publisher object>, <Publisher: Publisher object>]
```

Not sure why I'm getting more objects and why I cannot view the outputs of the unicode...

Thank you for your help!

**http://django-book.readthedocs.org/en/latest/chapter05.html is the link to the specific chapter!!!

Comment: what is the link of your tutorial?

Comment: @cathy the link has been updated on the post

Comment: Do you call save anywhere before you try to list it? Somehow you've save 2 extra copies somewhere. Perhaps you tried saving in an earlier bit?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I didn't because I was following the tutorial pretty closely but that may have occured. Whats bothering me the most is that  the unicode isn't displaying any of the objects =/

Comment: Surely these are older ones which have not been cleared since they have no unicode repr.

Comment: I just deleted all the objects and the duplicate problem has been fixed! However, the object attributes still arent displaying =[

Comment: Is the indentation correct? i.e. \_\_unicode\_\_ is correctly set as the Publisher's class method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this sample:

**models.py**

```
class Debt(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,
        help_text="Name to identify your debt.")
    due_day = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        help_text="Day of the month payment is due.")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{0}".format(self.user)
```

**views.py**

```
def debt(request):

return render(request, 'debt.html', {
    'debts': Debt.objects.filter(),
})
```

**debt.html**

```
 {% for debt in debts %}
     {{debt.user}} - {{debt.name}} <br/>
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: welcome, I'm a newbie here. I just want to share what I have learn and also learning from here.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have run the code twice. The values are already saved in the database. When you run it again, two more values get saved and they are duplicates.

Comment: I just deleted all the objects and the duplicate problem has been fixed! However, the object attributes still arent displaying =[

Comment: You are printing publisher_list. so its displaying those objects inside the list. To display attributes, loop through the list and access each attribute. For e.g. you can do publisher_list[0].name

Comment: The display problem was fixed as well as soon as I deleted the objects! thank you for your help!!!